Unable to replay a level that was skipped
Somehow accidently skipped a level in Lego Harry Potter years 1-4. When playing level 2-4 near the end, I got the game stuck and had to exit out to try to replay it. However when I exited, the flag was set for having the level cleared, and I was unable to go back in. Now the level can't be picked in free play. I was planning on 100%ing the game. Is there some way to force the level or is my save game hardlocked?


Related: Tom Riddle level missing?. Note this other question has no answers or comments either.

Unfortunately, this seems like a known bug. Leaving level 2-4 for any reason after the Moaning Myrtle fight causes the level to lock, with no apparent fix.
This reddit link suggests you'll have to restart, or find a save file with the same amount of progress. If you're using a system with any kind of save backups (the game itself does not keep backups) you could try reverting to an earlier save.

This is what I found too.

Yep. Was able to confirm from the sources you listed. It's basically what I expected, and I've already accepted it at this point. Thanks for giving me a definitive answer. Now when I start replaying I won't be wondering if I absolutely had to
